# Show html partial on link active/click - Bootstrap with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a html file in my Rails 4 app which has a header and some common text applicable to each of the relevant policies. The common text has three link tags (not currently linked to anything) called: Terms, Privacy, Copyright.

I then have 3 partials in my views folder which contains the content for each policy (called _terms.html.erb, _privacy.html.erb and _copyright.html.erb). I want to show the content of the partial beneath the common text area, as follows:

1. when the page first loads, I want to display the Terms partial.
2. when one of the the other policy names is clicked, i want to display the relevant partial.

I have tried adapting Bootstrap js collapse as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Terms", data-toggle="collapseTerms", aria-expanded="false", aria-controls="collapseTerms" %>


            <div class="collapse" id="collapseTerms">
                <div class="well">
                    <%= render 'stac/terms'  %>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The above doesnt work - it gives an error that says: undefined local variable or method `data'  (I don't know what this means)

How do I do this. I have made some js form helpers for circumstances where I've wanted to hide nested forms until an earlier form input is created, but it's not really the same situation this time, because i want the terms partial to display until one of the other two is clicked, at which time, I want the relevant partial to display beneath the common text.

How do you render a partial if a link is clicked, subject to one of them being rendered until one of the other links are clicked?

My entire effort to use Bootstrap Tabs is:

ATTEMPT 1

```
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href "#terms" aria-controls="terms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Terms</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#privacy" aria-controls="privacy" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Privacy</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#licence" aria-controls="licence" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Licence</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#trust" aria-controls="trust" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Trust</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#reliance" aria-controls="reliance" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Reliance</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#pricing" aria-controls="pricing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pricing</a></li>

  </ul>


<div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="terms"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/terms'  %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="privacy"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/privacy' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="licence"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/licence' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="trust"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/trust' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="importantnotice"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/bby' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="pricing"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/pricing' %></div>

            </div>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
$('#myTabs a:first').tab('show')
<% end %>
```

When I try this I get ugly styling and tabs that you can click on. Nothing happens when you click and I'm only mildly concerned about the styling given how many other problems subsist.

ATTEMPT 2 (which is the style I would prefer to use if it can be made to work)

Mostly the same as tab 1, except that I tried to make the list of options which Bootstrap styles like a navbar look more like the rest of my formatting:

```
<div role="presentation" class="intpol1","active"> <%= link_to "Terms", "#collapseTerms", 'data-toggle'=>"collapse", 'aria-expanded'=>"false", 'aria-controls'=>"collapseTerms" %></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div role="presentation" class="intpol1"> <%= link_to "Privacy", "#collapsePrivacy", 'data-toggle'=>"collapse", 'aria-expanded'=>"false", 'aria-controls'=>"collapsePrivacy" %></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="intpol1">Licence</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="intpol1">Trust</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="intpol1">Reliance</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="intpol1">Pricing</div>
            </div>


<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="terms"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/terms'  %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="privacy"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/privacy' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="licence"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/licence' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="trust"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/trust' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="importantnotice"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/bby' %></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="pricing"><%= render 'static/intpolicy/pricing' %></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>  


<%= javascript_tag do %>
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
$('#myTabs a:first').tab('show')
<% end %>
```

From this attempt you can see that only the first two labels appear as links (intentional- I didn't finish this attempt because the first two links don't work).

All of the text inside the render/partial files appears in a row (just ignoring the intended tabbed display).

I can't find any errors in this.  How do you use Bootstrap Tabs?  My console inspector displays css warnings (with bootstrap sass generally but no errors).

One difference between these attempts is that the first one - when you hover over a tab, the bottom of the screen says go to #terms, whereas when you hover over the link in the second one it says go to #collapseTerms

Another curious thing is that, I changed the second attempt to refer to the #terms & #privacy as id="terms" or id ="privacy":

```
<div role="presentation" class="intpol1","active"> <%= link_to "Terms", id="#terms", 'data-toggle'=>"collapse", 'aria-expanded'=>"false", 'aria-controls'=>"terms" %></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div role="presentation" class="intpol1"> <%= link_to "Privacy", id="#privacy", 'data-toggle'=>"collapse", 'aria-expanded'=>"false", 'aria-controls'=>"privacy" %></div>
```

The effect of this is that when you click on the second attempt links for terms, it moves the footer on the bottom of the page up, to put it on top of the start of the html in the terms partial. You click the terms link again and it goes away. Strangely, the same thing doesn't happen when you click the privacy link.

Comment: As a starting point, change the syntax of your link to to be: `<%= link_to "Terms", 'data-toggle'=>"collapseTerms", 'aria-expanded'=>"false", 'aria-controls'=>"collapseTerms" %>`. When using a link to, any attribute with a dash in it must be surrounded in quotes. That should at least get the anchor tag displayed correctly and you can troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Actually, you have other issues too, I think it should be more like: `<%= link_to "Terms", "#collapseTerms", 'data-toggle'=>"collapse", 'aria-expanded'=>"false", 'aria-controls'=>"collapseTerms" %>` i.e. the href should point to the id you are trying to show/hide and the data-toggle should be "collapse"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's obvious from your question that you're looking for an overall view on how to do this.

There are two ways to do it:

1. Pull the partials through *ajax* (load them dynamically)
2. Preload the partials on your page & *show* them with JS

I'll detail both methods:

---

**Ajax**

The first - [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (**A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ml) - is to pull the partial code through an *asynchronous* request.

This is basically where you have extra data on your server you wish to serve out of scope of the current request -- IE an *asynchronous* request.

We use ajax requests for all sorts of reasons, but one of the main is to give us the ability to call extended functionality *after* the page has loaded (makes app more efficient).

You could use the [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) ajax wrapper from JQuery to pull the partials after a link click:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.html.erb
$(document).on("click", "a.", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   url = "stac/" + $(this).attr("href");
   $.get(url);
});
```

This will have to be accompanied with some `routes` and `controller` code:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :stacs, only: :show

#app/controllers/stacts_controller.rb
class StacsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @stac = Stac.find params[:id]
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js
         format.html
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to handle the response in the server-side JS:

```
#app/views/stacs/show.js.erb
$("body").append("<%=j render 'specs/#{params[:id]}' %>");
```

---

**Bootstrap**

> when one of the the other policy names is clicked, i want to display the relevant partial

Sounds like you want to use the [*accordion*](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) module in Bootstrap.

If you're asking a question about *Bootstrap* (which I'm not overly versed in), you'll be looking at preloading all your partials, and *revealing* them with JS.

This is quite simple:

```
#app/views/pages.html.erb
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <% %w(terms copyright privacy).each_with_index do |folder, i| %>
       <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading#{i}">
              <%= link_to "Terms", data: {toggle="collapse#{folder}"}, aria: { expanded: "false", controls: "collapse#{folder}" } %>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse" id="collapse<%= folder %>">
             <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<%= i %>">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                    <%= render 'stac/terms'  %>
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. I was trying to use Bootstrap Tabs actually (rather than the accordion, but am having trouble setting it up). I've not been any more successful with the ajax set up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks Rich. I tried both of these options (I was actually trying to use Bootstrap Tabs originally - but I couldn't figure out how to implement it). I tried your ajax example but get this error: 
The partial name (specs/#{params[:id]}) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with underscore, and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and underscores. Not sure at all why that is issued but I didn't understand the reasons for the changes in the code. The partials just have static html - so no ids. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That partial error looks like an interpolation error.